# What does "I swore some" mean?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-choice

The entire paragraph is

> 'I told the man that valets me that I was feeling pretty bad, and I got myself up to look like death. That wasn't difficult, for I'm no slouch at disguises. Then I got a corpse - you can always get a body in London if you know where to go for it. I fetched it back in a trunk on the top of a four-wheeler, and I had to be assisted upstairs to my room. You see I had to pile up some evidence for the inquest. I went to bed and got my man to mix me a sleeping- draught, and then told him to clear out. He wanted to fetch a doctor, **but I swore some and said I couldn't abide leeches.** When I was left alone I started in to fake up that corpse. He was my size, and I judged had perished from too much alcohol, so I put some spirits handy about the place. The jaw was the weak point in the likeness, so I blew it away with a revolver. I daresay there will be somebody tomorrow to swear to having heard a shot, but there are no neighbours on my floor, and I guessed I could risk it. So I left the body in bed dressed up in my pyjamas, with a revolver lying on the bed-clothes and a considerable mess around. Then I got into a suit of clothes I had kept waiting for emergencies. I didn't dare to shave for fear of leaving tracks, and besides, it wasn't any kind of use my trying to get into the streets. I had had you in my mind all day, and there seemed nothing to do but to make an appeal to you. I watched from my window till I saw you come home, and then slipped down the stair to meet you ... There, Sir, I guess you know about as much as me of this business.'

but I swore some and said I couldn't abide leeches ".  It is from *The Thirty-Nine Steps*. http://learnlibrary.com/thirty-nine-steps/39steps_chapter_one_-_the.htm

Comment: Have you looked the words up in a dictionary? Why are you still confused? Tell us that and we can better help you.

Comment: It isn't idiomatic to me (I'm British, but the character speaking is American), but it's not hard to guess that he means "I swore a little".

Comment: @randomhead I do have looked the words up in a dictionary. To be more accurate, more than one dictionary. They all give you meanings in general, rather than specific.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Can you please give me an example of "I swore a little"?

Comment: What don't you understand about James's answer? He said a few 'swear-words' to his manservant, perhaps something like "Damn you to hell, [Name], I can't abide leeches!"

Comment: I certainly understand James's answer. Please see my reply to his answer. You give me a good answer too this time. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

"I swore some":  Swearing is using bad language (like "shit" etc). In this case to offend the man who wanted to get the doctor and make him go away. The use of "some" is rare but it is an adverb that tells you how much he swore (he said some swear words)

"Leeches" are a type of blood sucking worm that were used by doctors to remove blood from a patient that they thought had too much blood.  As this was a common treatment, doctors became called "leeches" by people who disliked their high charges.

So it means "I used some bad language and told him I disliked doctors."

Comment: Excellent answer! Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

[Merriam-Webster *some*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-some)

> adverb 2a : in some degree : somewhat felt some better
> b : to some degree or extent : a little
> *the cut bled some*
> *I need to work on it some more*

It means the same as "I swore a little", that is he or she swore a small, indeterminate amount.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of "I swore a little" as James K did?